# Arrange $n$ people in a row with conditions

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n$ people, including Alice, Bob and Eve.
How many ways are there to arrange those $n$ people in a row, such that Alice is left to Eve and Bob is right to Eve.

My (wrong) thought:
We choose places for Alice, Bob and Eve:  $C(n, 3)$. There is only one valid arrangement. Then, we multiply by $(n-3)!$ for the rest.

The right answer is:
$$\left( {\matrix{
   n  \cr 
   2  \cr 
 } } \right) \cdot \left( {\matrix{
   {n - 2}  \cr 
   2  \cr 
 } } \right) \cdot (n - 4)! \cdot 1 \cdot 1$$

Why?

Comment: Are they directly beside Eve or somewhere else to the left/right of Eve in the row?

Comment: Don't have to be directly beside Eve.

Comment: As far as I can tell your "wrong" thought is correct. The "right" answer is correct for the following question: There are $n$ people, among them Alice, Bob, Eve and...Dave. Alice must be to the left of Eve, and Bob must be to the left of Dave.

Comment: The "right" answer is treating the Eves in Alice/Eve and Bob/Eve as two different people, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fisrt: I'm pretty sure that your answer is correct.

Second: the "correct" answer makes no sense, since the problem doesn't tell that there are actually more than three people in the row. Try to substitue $n=3$ and you get the "binomial coefficient" $\binom 12$.